# Positively invariant set

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

In my research I need to show that the set $$S:=\left\{x_{i}\in [0,1] , y_{i} \in [0,c_{i}] ; i = 1,\dots , n; \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}+y_{i}) =1\right\},$$ is positively invariant with respect the following system of ordinary differential equation.
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dx_{i}}{dt}=-\sum_{j\neq i}^{n}a_{ij}x_{i}+\Sigma_{j\neq i}^{n}a_{ji}x_{j}+f_{i}(x_{i}, y_{i}),\\
\frac{dy_{i}}{dt}=-\sum_{j\neq i}^{n}b_{ij}y_{i}+\Sigma_{j\neq i}^{n}b_{ji}y_{j}+g_{i}(x_{i}, y_{i})
\end{eqnarray}

for $i= 1, \dots, n$. The functions $f_{i}$ and $g_{i}$ are nonlinear and continous with continous first partial derivatives. The terms $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ are nonnegative. 
I understand that the set $S$ is a subset of $n$-dimensional Euclidean simplex.

My question is how do I show that $S$ is positively invariant with respect to the system given. Any ideas, references are apreciated.

Comment: It isn't, unless there's something you've left out.  In order for $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i + y_i)$ to stay at $1$, the sum of the derivatives must be $0$, and you've given us no reason to think that would be the case.

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to mention that $f_{i}+g_{i}=0$, for all $i=1, \dots, n.$ So that would mean the derivative of $\Sigma_{i}^{n}(x_{i}+y_{i})$ equals zero. Is that enough to show that the set $S$ is positively invariant.

Comment: Well, the next things we want are $\dfrac{dx_i}{dt}\ge 0$ when $x_i=0$ and $\le 0$ when $x_i = 1$, and $\dfrac{dy_i}{dt} \ge 0$ when $y_i = 0$ and $\le 0$ when $y_i = c_i$.